# Using custom components in Cappuccino with Interface Builder

Tags: cappuccino

I know that in Cocoa, in order to use custom component in Interface Builder I should go to property inspector panel and change, say, my standard NSView to the custom one.

Is there any solution for using custom components in Cappuccino while laying out components in Interface Builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the exact same thing.

You have your CPSupaView, you just drop a view in IB and you change the class name to CPSupaView.